# In TestRigor, how do you "grab value" in the API response?

Tags: testrigor

If I'm making a POST call, and the response is 200 ok. How would I grab one of the ID fields listed in the response? The documentation seems to hint that 'and get "JsonPath" and save it as "variableName" ' will do the trick, but no luck.

The goal is to use the ID field that is captured in the response as a param in another PUT call that I intend to make in the next step of the test case.

For example, my test case would look something like this:

//Step 1: Create record_id
call api  "<API_URL>" with headers "a:a" and "b:b" and body "body" and get "record_id" and save it as "var_record_id"

//Step 2: Update the specific record_id from POST call to a permitted state
call api  "<API_URL>" with headers "a:a" and "b:b" and body from the string with parameters text starting from next line and ending with [END]
{
"param": "var_record_id",
"state": "permit"

}
[END]

Answer (score 1):

This is how i use it:
call api post from the string with parameters `${urlApi}/${vehicleInfoUrlPageName}/${requestSessionApiEndPoint}` with headers  from the string with parameters `${ContentTypeHeader}` and body from the string with parameters text starting from next line and ending with [END]

`${requestBody}`

[END] and get `$` and save it as `endpointResponseData` and get `$.sessionId` and save it as `sessionIdFromResponse` get `$.success` and save it as `successFlag` and get `$.pId` and save it as `pidFromResponse`  and get `$.data` and save it as `dataObjectFromResponse` and get `$.error` and save it as `errorObjectFromResponse` and then check that http code is `200`